# Can't access value correctly drop down list asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to asp mvc, so I was trying to understand how to get selected value from drop down list. Now what I want is to see the selected value as text in my view. After searching several examples, I have this code in controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
        TaskModel task = new TaskModel();
        task.Tasks = FillTaskList();          
        return View(task);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(TaskModel task)
    {
        task.Tasks = FillTaskList();
        ViewBag.Message = task.TaskName;
        return View(task);
    }

    private static List<SelectListItem> FillTaskList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["contingentConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            string query = " SELECT TaskId, TaskName FROM Task";
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (sdr.Read())
                    {
                        items.Add(new SelectListItem
                        {
                            Text = sdr["TaskName"].ToString(),
                            Value = sdr["TaskId"].ToString()
                        });
                    }
                }
                con.Close();
            }
        }
        return items;
    }
```

This is my view:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@model WebApplication1.Models.TaskModel

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>    
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.TaskId, Model.Tasks, "--Select task--", null)
            </div>
            <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-success submit">Send</button><br/>
            <span style="color:green">@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)</span>
        }        
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is my model:

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class TaskModel
    {
        public List<SelectListItem> Tasks { get; set; }
        public int TaskId { get; set; }
        public string TaskName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem is that I keep getting null instead of "TaskName" value here,

```
ViewBag.Message = task.TaskName;
```

but

```
ViewBag.Message = task.TaskId;
```

is processing correctly and I can see it in ViewBag.Message. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use your browser console or Fiddler or similar to look at the payload that is getting posted.  I expect that you will find that `TaskId` (from the dropdown) is the only property in the payload or at least the only property that has a value in the payload.  The ASP.NET model binding does it best to map POSTed value into the type you specify -- but it does not have any past state.

If you think about your use case, `TaskId` is the only value that is needed to be posted back.  You should use the ID that gets posted back to query the latest values (including `TaskName`) for that TaskId.

Comment: Seems this is really so, thanks for advice!

Comment: My pleasure.  Welcome to StackOverflow -- #SOReadyToHelp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem: In your action POST, it only mapping TaskId from dropdown, you need filter in TaskList to check selected task in list. If selected task in list, then set `ViewBag.Message = selectedTask.Text`

You need update your action code for POST:

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(TaskModel task)
 {
            task.Tasks = FillTaskList();
            var selectedTask = task.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Value == task.TaskId.ToString());
            if (selectedTask != null)
            {
                ViewBag.Message = selectedTask.Text;
            }

            return View(task);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Html.HiddenFor Helper method to create a hidden variable in the form for this property

```
@Html.HiddenFor(x => x.TaskName)
```

Use javascript to set selected text

```
$(function () {
  $("form").submit(function(){
    var selText = $("#TaskId option:selected").text();
    $("#TaskName").val(selText);           
  });
});
```

Then in controller you can get

```
string value = model.TaskName;
```